# I created an ID "slider" and displayed it to be inline-flex but chrome isn't showing the items aligned horizontally, Why so?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
The HTML code contains an ID with some text inside it
 HTML code---
<div id="slider">
Some text here ......

</div>
<div id="slider">
Some text here

</div> 

CSS --
#slider {
display: inline-flex
   }
```

Display is set to inline-flex here

The flex isn't applying on chrome browser, why?

Comment: A css class would be more appropriate; ids should be unique. Can you add an embedded code snippet demonstrating this effect?

Comment: Thank you sir. I already fixed it. It was a slight mistake though

Answer (score 1):

Could be one of the following:

- You missed a semi-colon(`;`) at the end of the css line.
- You have multiple id's with same value, consider changing then to `class` instead of `id`, and use in the css the `.slider` selector.

Comment: @HarrisonUdechukwu You can click on the V next to answer to accept it.